# how to write order preserving minimal perfect hash for integer keys?

Tags: c, hash

I have searched stackoverflow and google and cant find exactly what im looking for which is this:

I have a set of 4 byte unsigned integers keys, up to a million or so, that I need to use as an index into a table.  The easiest would be to simply use the keys as an array index but I dont want to have a 4gb array when Im only going to use a couple of million entries!  The table entries and keys are sequential so I need a hash function that preserves order.

e.g.
        `keys = {56, 69, 3493, 49956, 345678, 345679,....etc}`

I want to translate the keys into `{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5,....etc}`

The keys could potentially be any integer but there wont be more than 2 million in total.  The number will vary as keys (and corresponding array entries) will be deleted but new keys will always be higher numbered than the previous highest numbered key.

In the above example, if key 69 was deleted, then the hash integer returned on hashing 3493 should be 1 (rather than 2) as it then becomes the 2nd lowest number.

I hope I'm explaining this right.  Is the above possible with any fast efficient hashing solution?  I need the translation to take in the low 100s of nS though deletion I expect to take longer.  I looked at CMPH but couldn't find any usage examples that didn't involved getting the data from a file.  It needs to run under linux and compiled with gcc using pure C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I don't know if I understand what exactly you want to do.

It seems you are trying to obtain the index number in the "array" (or "list") of sequentialy ordered integers that you have stored somewhere.

If you have stored these integer values in an array, then the algorithm that returns the index integer in optimal time is **Binary Search**.

[Binary Search Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm)

Since your list is known to be in order, then binary search works in O(log(N)) time, which is very fast.

If you delete an element in the list of "keys", the Binary Search Algorithm works anyway, without extra effort or space (however, the operation of removing one element in the list enforces to you, naturally, to move all the elements being at the right of the deleted element).

You only have to provide three data to the Ninary Search Algorithm: the array, the size of the array, and the desired key, of course.

Comment: Yeah binary search is what I'm using at the moment and it works ok but I was hoping a hash function would be faster.  The application is time critical so saving uS here and there adds up.

Comment: +1 / @poby: hash functions aren't a good fit for this - dynamic perfect hashing for million+ elements isn't practical, let alone preserving order, and without any gaps!  Re "then the algorithm that returns the index integer in optimal time is Binary Search" - binary search has the best worst-case characteristics, but an [interpolation search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_search) has `O(log(log N))` average for evenly distributed numbers... it may not help but could be worth benchmarking.

Comment: @TonyD: I appreciate your comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a full Python implementation [here](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=119). See also the materials available [here](http://iswsa.acm.org/mphf/mphf.py). If you only need to decode the dictionary, the simplest way to go is to modify the Python code to make it spit out a C file defining the necessary array, and reimplement only the lookup function.

Answer (score 0):

It could be solved by using two dynamic allocated arrays: One for the "keys" and one for the data for the keys.

To get the data for a specific key, you first find in in the key-array, and its index in the key-array is the index into the data array.

When you remove a key-data pair, or want to insert a new item, you reallocate the arrays, and copy over the keys/data to the correct places.

I don't claim this to be the best or most effective solution, but it is one solution to your problem anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an order preserving minimal perfect hash, because any old hash would do. You don't want to use a 4GB array, but with 2 MB of items, you wouldn't mind using 3 MB of lookup entries.

A standard implementation of a hash map will do the job. It will allow you to delete and add entries and assign any value to entries as you add them.

This leaves you with the question "What hash function might I use on integers?" The usual answer is to take the remainder when dividing by a prime. The prime is chosen to be a bit larger than your expected data. For example, if you expect 2M of items, then choose a prime around 3M.